# Installing Scipy in Python3.3 on Windows7

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

How can I install Scipy into python3.3 on Windows7(I have Numpy installed)? The official binary only support up to Python 3.2.
Please give detailed instructions.

Comment: Python 3.3 is backwards-compatible to Python 3.2, so have you tried installing the Python 3.2 binary?

Comment: But the Python 3.2 binary installer in not processed because it cannot find Python 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer related to your question
Unofficial package

[Where to download Scipy for Python3.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15662643/where-to-download-scipy-for-python3-3)