# Where to download Scipy for Python3.3?

Tags: python, scipy

I want to install Scipy for Python3.3 in Windows. But I only found Scipy installation file for Python up to the version 3.2 in the following link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.12.0b1/

So is it still not available at this time? Any suggestions?

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

Comment: The "latest" scipy source is available on github https://github.com/scipy/scipy

Comment: Thanks bernie for your link.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I highly recommend getting all of the components of [`Scipy-stack`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy-stack), which is just below the `scipy` files linked in the comment above. Unfortunately the maintainer hasn't updated `scipy-stack` to 3.3 yet (I emailed him about it), but all of the components (`numpy-MKL`, `scipy`, `matplotlib`, `ipython`, `pandas`, `sympy`, and `nose`), as well as all the dependencies (`Python-dateutil`, `distribute`, `gmpy`, `PIL`, `pygments`, `pyreadline`, `pytz`, `statsmodels`, and `tornado`) have 3.3 versions available for both Win32 and AMD64. Depending on what sort of computing you'll be doing, these packages will give you a great start, and as they're all from the same source they should all work well together.

**UPDATE**

I just heard from Christoph Gohlke, and he is holding off on updating `scipy-stack` until `numpy-1.7.1`, `scipy-0.12`, and `ipython-0.13.2` are released, so probably a few months. If you want to build your own version, his [`redist_wininst.py`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/redist_wininst.py.html) script lets you do just that.

**UPDATE 2**

[`scipy-stack`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy-stack) has been updated with new versions of its components, for both Python 2.7 and 3.3. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Matt. I have already installed Numpy, matplotlib for Python 3.3. So I just need Scipy for 3.3.